# python matplot.hist - remove gaps between bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I wish to create a histogram with no gaps between the bars.  Tried to add argument `bin` or `range` but with no success.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

population = 100
possible_answers = 4
scores = np.random.choice(range(possible_answers),population)
plt.hist(scores)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with gaps between the bars]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `bins` argument to adjust which bins are used.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

population = 100
possible_answers = 4
scores = np.random.choice(range(possible_answers),population)
plt.hist(scores, bins=range(possible_answers+1), ec="k")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you want to shift the bins

```
plt.hist(scores, bins=np.arange(possible_answers+1)-0.5, ec="k")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to set the x-axis numbers (1,2,3,4) to be on the middle of each bar?

Comment: what does the argument ec="k" does? i dont see it on the documentation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: ec = "k" produces black lines around the bars.